# pan with one finger

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I want to prevent the user from panning while pinch rotating or zooming,
so the solution I have come with is to limit the user to pan only with one finger.
so I was able to do that with the following code:

```
var interactions = map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction)   {
if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DragPan) {
    pan = interaction;
}

}, this);


//disable pan with 2 fingers by redefine the handleDownEvent function and call
//to the original handleDownEvent_ function only when the user use 1 finger.
var panDownEvent = pan.handleDownEvent_;
pan.handleDownEvent_ = function (e) {

    if(pan.targetPointers.length >1) return false;
    panDownEvent.call(pan,e);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that when I am using this code from some reason the tiles lazy load stop working **only on mobile**.

I will be graceful if you can add an api option to limit the pan to only one finger or give me other solution,
or event better, how to trigger the ol lazy load function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenLayers map is created with some **default interactions**. The [PinchZoom](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.PinchZoom.html) interaction is one of them. Any default interaction **can be disabled** when creating the map, for example to disable the pinch zoom interaction, you can do this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
    pinchZoom: false
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Learn more about this in the [list of interactions](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.html) page, which includes details about `ol.interaction.defaults`, i.e. the list of default interactions in an OpenLayers map.

Try this and see if that makes your other issue disappear.

Comment: hi, it is not my problem, the problem is when the user is pinching he also panning, so when I disabled the pan when using 2 fingers by override the handleDownEvent_ in the original object from some reason the tiles lazy load stop working only on mobile. thanks anyway.